# Atualizar uma coluna a cada 2 horas

Tags: sql-server

Estou com uma coluna com valores mais preciso que a cada 2 horas ela aumente +1.
para que o jogador compre o quanto antes.

```html
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Produtos_Offer](
    [x_Item] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Preço] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Valor] [int] NOT NULL
)

UPDATE Produtos_Offer SET Valor = Valor +1 WHERE x_Item = 0267
```

Comment: cria um job e agenda para executar  a cada 2 horas

Comment: Note que da maneira como fez seu SET você está atribuindo 1 ao campo Valor e não somando 1, vide a forma correta na resposta do Rodrigo Nascentes. Quanto à execução periódica siga a dica do Ricardo Pontual.

Answer (score 0):

Para atribuição de adição no SQL Server você pode usar o operador `+=`

```
UPDATE Produtos_Offer SET Valor += 1 WHERE x_Item = 0267
```

Isso tem o mesmo efeito efeito que:

```
UPDATE Produtos_Offer SET Valor = Valor + 1 WHERE x_Item = 0267
```

Comment: A sim, obrigado. Corrigido!

Comment: @Jor - Poderia por favor marcar a resposta como útil? Brigadão.

Comment: Sem Level amigo